# How to properly convert uuid to BINARY(16)?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, uuid

I have an id field of type `BINARY(16)` in a mysql table.

I generate the following id: `66e2105c-bff5-4206-a9cc-e212f5622368`

With this code:

```
const v = uuidV4Bytes(16);
```

The insert via sequalize is:

```
INSERT INTO SPORTS(Id,Name,HouseId,Date,Active)
        VALUES ('66e2105c-bff5-4206-a9cc-e212f5622368','SPORTNAME',1, '2020-05-04', 0)
```

Problem:

```
Error Code: 1406. Data too long for column 'Id' at row
```

Im trying to convert a uuid to a binary(16) but apperently Im getting a value that is to big. 
How do I solve this?

Comment: Looks like you got your column names and DATA a bit muddled up. `Name` : 1? and HouseId : SPORTNAME??

Comment: just a copy paste issue, updated.  Main problem remains

Comment: `66e2105c-bff5-4206-a9cc-e212f5622368` thats MORE than 16 bytes. Its more like 36 bytes.

Comment: I gatherd that but the thing is that Im new at this and as far as I understood these methods should generate a 16  bytes but im missing something.

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah but the dashes position never changes and don't have to be stored, so then you're left with 32 characters, and those 32 characters are in base16 hex, if you convert those 32 characters from base16 (hex) to base256 (bytes), then you're left with 16 base256 characters (or 16 bytes) ^^

Comment: @hanshenrik OK, so now how would you search the table based on a uuid?

Comment: @RiggsFolly one way to do it would be: ```SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE `id` = UNHEX(REPLACE('66e2105c-bff5-4206-a9cc-e212f5622368','-',''));```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as long as it's always in the form `8-4-4-4-12` hex characters, you could just have MySQL do it for you with REPLACE() and UNHEX()

```
INSERT INTO SPORTS(Id,Name,HouseId,WDate,Active)
    VALUES (UNHEX(REPLACE('66e2105c-bff5-4206-a9cc-e212f5622368','-','')),'SPORTNAME',1, '2020-05-04', 0)
```

Comment: Jump started my brain to search for the right thing. My answer below is the way I did it but accepting this since it pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: What if I need to perform query like `SELECT id, fname FROM table_name WHERE id=UNHEX(REPLACE('4568-7899-2543-8yu5', "-", ""))`, it returns me result like: `id:<buffer 45 68 78 99 25 43 8y u5, fname:john`. Is there any way to convert this buffer value back to the original format & show in response data from database (using Aurora-AWS with nodejs)?

Comment: @bubble-cord maybe ```SELECT CONCAT(
 HEX(SUBSTRING(id, 1, 4)),'-',
 HEX(SUBSTRING(id, 5, 2)),'-',
 HEX(SUBSTRING(id, 7, 2)),'-',
 HEX(SUBSTRING(id, 9, 2)),'-',
 HEX(SUBSTRING(id, 11, 6))
) AS `id`, `fname` FROM table_name WHERE id = '4568-7899-2543-8yu5'```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @hanshenrik I started searching for a way to use UNHEX in nodeexpress.

I found the following:

```
const byteValue = Buffer.from(uuidV4Bytes(16).replace('-', ''), 'hex')
```

This did the trick. However I can not say that this is the most optimal way but it solved my problem.